# How to add fuzziness to text field if the field contains date

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field that contains date (format 2023-12-25) but its text type.
I need to do a date search with a possible typo. Tried to do it like this

```
POST _msearch/
{"index" : "some_index"}
{"query": {"bool" : {"must" : [{"match": {"birthDate": {"query": "1939-02-21", "fuzziness": 1}}}]}}}
```

It doesnt work. If i change the date to 1939-05-17, the result remains the same. Even if i try 17-05-1939.

It's strange, but with other text-type fields fuzziness works correctly.

I expect elastic to find the rigth date (for example, 1939-02-21) if the input is 1939-02-22 or 1939-03-21. But not the 1939-03-22.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch measure the similarity **between two text string** with [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) during [fuzzy query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html).

> In information theory, linguistics, and computer science, the
> Levenshtein distance is a string metric for measuring the difference
> between two sequences.

Even though you index the date as a string, you cannot measure the similarity between numbers, special characters, or anything expect alphabet. e.g. You can measure the similarity between `"shark" and "shard"` but `NOT` `"1" and "2"` or `"*" and "#"`. So you cannot measure the similarity between dates too.

Maybe, you can use [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) with some dynamic values.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
        "gte": "now-30d/d",
        "lte": "now/d".  <-- your filter here
      }
    }
  }
}
```